# Brown Chickens and egg frequency

Tags: stardew-valley

What determines the chance to get a brown chicken? Can I get it by incubating white eggs? And what determines the eggs frequency? I noticed that my chickens don't lay eggs everyday, I'm not treating they well?

Comment: There's ongoing speculation/research that suggests that chicken colour might depend on their name. Additionally, [this might help](http://www.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261286/what-makes-chickens-unhappy/)

Comment: By the name? That's strange... Any possible name that could get me a brown chicken? I need it for the animal bundle... And thanks, I thought that I don't need to pet the chickens, seems that is one of my current problems right now.

Comment: My one brown chicken is named Fotchley, if you want to check that theory.

Comment: I'll try that, I have a chick to born the next thay from the incubator. Do you know with a chick born from a large egg change something?

Comment: As far as I know, the colour and size of the egg has no effect on the chick.

Answer (score 1):

When I bought my two chickens I got one brown and one white. The color of egg represents the chicken you will get from incubator. I have gotten brown chickens from brown eggs and white chickens from white eggs.

I found that if I let the chickens outside, the egg laying was more random then if I closed the door and made sure they had food.

The pet function does increase pet's love for you. This in turn will help you get the large eggs. It took a little while but I finally got my large eggs for the community bundle.

Comment: Note that the game is imitating real life in this: broadly speaking, brown chickens lay brown eggs, and white chickens lay white eggs. (So when someone tries to tell you that brown eggs are somehow inherently healthier, they're talking utter nonsense.)

Comment: Note however that brown cows do not give chocolate milk.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a brown egg from traveling cart that appears south of the farm, in Cindersap Forest, on Fridays and Sundays. (The cart usually have a bunch of random items so you it might take a while to find brown egg for sale)

You can also try to keep buying chickens in Animal shop till you get a brown one (just sell white ones back)

From incubating an egg you can only get an animal that lays same types of egg you have put into incubator (e.g. white egg - white chicken)

To increase your chance of getting eggs daily, do not forget to pet your chickens every day, let them outside in all seasons (except winter) and do not forget to feed them.

Answer (score 0):

To get brown chickens from Marnie, really easy is just keep on going through the buying process where you have to select a coop. At the top, you will have a message saying "choose a coop for your new White/Brown chicken". buy the chicken colour you want